# LINQ dynamic case

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this method:

```
private string GetLanguage(String currentLanguage, dynamic entity)
{
    return (currentLanguage == "de" ? entity.language.German :
     currentLanguage == "fr" ? entity.language.French :
     currentLanguage == "en" ? entity.language.English :
     entity.language.English);
}
```

And I need this to return an LINQ Expression that do something like this SQL statement:

```
select (case when [french] is null then [english] else [french] end) as language 
from
```

How can I achieve this?

Tks

EDIT:

To be more specific:

I have something like this:

```
myId = 1;

from objects in context.Objects
                           where objects.Id== myId
select new
                           {
                               MyObject = new Models.MyObjects()
                               {
                                   Id = objects.ScrId,
                                   Title = LanguageFactory.GetLabelLanguage(objects.Labels)
                               }
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

And the MyObject.Title must be in some language (English, French, Dutch, etc.).
In SQL I resolved that by doing something like:

```
select id, (case when [french] is null then [english] else [french] end) as language 
from table
```

How can I do a LINQ expression that can be translated to something like the SQL query above?

Comment: You want the GetLanguage method to return a linq expression?

Comment: May I ask If you know the currentLanguage why do you try to produce such an sql like that.

Comment: Yes, that will be used in the main query, has the following:
select id, name, (case when [french] is null then [english] else [french] end) as language 
from table

Comment: Davut, because the column with the currentLanguage may have null values and i need the query to "fallback" to the default column, english

Comment: Why not query the different columns and handle the fallback in code? Your fallback scenario really isn't suited to translate well from LINQ to SQL...

Comment: Because I don't want to evaluate that in code. It would be more elegant to do this in a SQL Case, and I thought it was possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to call arbitrary functions in Linq-to-SQL. But you can use a `Expression`, like this:

```
private Expression<Func<DbObject, MyObject>> GetObjectWithLanguage =
    e => new MyObject
    {
        Id = e.ScrId,
        Title = e.currentLanguage == "de" ? e.Labels.language.German :
                e.currentLanguage == "fr" ? e.Labels.language.French :
                e.currentLanguage == "en" ? e.Labels.language.English :
                e.Labels.language.English
    };

...
var results = context.Objects.Where(e => e.Id == myId).Select(GetObjectWithLanguage);
```

This will use a `currentLanguage` property on the entity itself to determine what to return. However, if you want to pass `currentLanguage` as a parameter from your c# code, try this:

```
private Expression<Func<DbObject, MyObject>> GetObjectWithLanguage(string currentLanguage)
{
    if (currentLanguage == "de")
    {
        return e => new MyObject
        {
            Id = e.ScrId,
            Title = e.Labels.language.German
        }
    }
    else if (currentLanguage == "fr")
    {
        return e => new MyObject
        {
            Id = e.ScrId,
            Title = e.Labels.language.French
        }
    }
    ...
}

var results = context.Objects.Where(e => e.Id == myId).Select(GetObjectsWithLanguage("de"));
```

If you would like to create a general purpose method, I suggest you use generics rather than `dynamic` parameters, for example, suppose you have an interface like:

```
public interface ILanguageAware
{
    string CurrentLanguage { get; }
    string English { get; }
    string French { get; }
    string German { get; }
}

public class ObjectWithLanguage<T> where T : ILanguageAware
{
    public T OriginalObject { get; set; }
    string LanguageText { get; set; }
}

public Expression<Func<T, ObjectWithLanguage<T>>> GetObjectWithLanguage<T>() where T : ILanguageAware
{
    return x => new ObjectWithLanguage<T>
           {
               OriginalObject = x,
               LanguageText = x.CurrentLanguage == "de" ? x.German :
                              x.CurrentLanguage == "fr" ? x.French :
                              ...
           }
}

// extension method for convenience
public static IQueryable<ObjectWithLanguage<T>> SelectWithLanguage<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    return queryable.Select(GetObjectWithLanguage<T>());
}

var results = context.Objectss.Where(e => e.Id == myId).SelectWithLanguage();
```

Comment: First of all, tks.

Second, my goal is to have a generic public method  that receives an dynamic parameter, because I have a lot of model tabels that have the same language columns.
My current method returns an string, and i wanted it to return an LINQ Expression.

public string GetLanguage(String currentLanguage, dynamic entity)
{
    return (currentLanguage == "de" ? entity.language.German :
     currentLanguage == "fr" ? entity.language.French :
     currentLanguage == "en" ? entity.language.English :
     entity.language.English);
}



I am confused in how to convert your code to my goal.

Comment: currently I have the following method:

public Expression<Func<dynamic, string>> GetObjectWithLanguage(dynamic entity)
        {
            string currentLanguage = GetContextLanguage();

            Expression<Func<dynamic, string>> ret = e => currentLanguage == "de" ? entity.German :
                currentLanguage == "fr" ? entity.French :
                currentLanguage == "en" ? entity.English :
                entity.English;

            return ret;
        }

With the following error, "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. You may not be able to do with `dynamic` parameters, but a generic method would probably work. I've updated my answer with some code that should provide you some pointers.